# Matrix multiplication python shapes not aligned

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I am currently working on an assignment where we have to multiply four matrices (a.T, b, M, a.T) and I keep getting the error "ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)".

I have tried implementing it without the transpose which works fine but as soon as I add the transpose, the error shows up so I am assuming it has something to do with the transpose. I have never programmed in Python before so I would really appreciate some help.

```py
def matrix_function(M, a, b):
    part1=a.T.dot(b)
    part2=M.dot(a.T)
    out=part1.dot(part2)

    return out

with: 
M = np.array(range(4)).reshape((2,2))
a = np.array([[1,1]])
b = np.array([[10, 10]]).T
```

The assignment says the expected result is 
(20 100) of shape (2,1) but I get neither the result nor the shape right. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: you are trying to perform dot on np arrays with shape `2*1` and `2*1` in `part1=a.T.dot(b)` , and as you said if you remove transpose from `b = np.array([[10, 10]]).T` , it works fine

Comment: I know that I can't multiply matrices of these dimensions but the task states that I have to use the transpose. Is there a way to implement this differently so that it works?

Comment: Have you read the `np.dot` docs?  experimented with those examples?  Do the calculations by hand as well, so you understand where the numbers come from.